# Multiplayer game in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

In the **OnNetworkSpawn** method as shown in the image, why are we checking for the owner of the instance as every client connected to the server will run his own scripts and will always be the owner of his own instance on the server (right ?) but if I remove this statement and then run the game, input on one client move all of the connected clients.

Edit :- I am new to Stack overflow and not good in asking questions so please tell me if I should elaborate more :-)

[image: Check the OnNetworkSpawn method]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you don't know how to ask, read about it at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). First thing: Don't post code as image, post it as text in a code block. That way, users who cannot see images can read it and one can copy your code to post an answer.

Comment: Thank you @ChrᴉzremembersMonica. will keep in mind everything you said :)

Answer (score 0):

So basically what the **if(IsOwner)** statement is doing checks to see if the client is the owner of his own player, If you dont include that it doesnt check what players the client owns so it moves all of them. If you do include the statement it will check what player the client owns and only move that one player.

Comment: But why do we have to check for ownership as every client is running his own script so he is always the owner of his own player object .. Isn't it ?

Comment: Nope, if you do not run the if statement check it will assume it owns ALL of the player objects as the client technically runs every script

Comment: Okay lets take an example, there are 2 clients on the server. Both will run their own scripts and for each of them they will always be the owner, now let us assume that ```if(IsOwner)``` check is not there and we have a simple move method in the update loop. Now if I am the client 1 and you are the client 2, if I try to move my player object, how the object linked with you can move as one player object is only linked to one corresponding client. ?